# Show that if $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{Q}$, then $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

I was proving the statement "if $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{Q}$, then $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$."

My idea was that if $f(x)=a$ for any $a\neq 0$ and for any $x\notin \mathbb{Q}$, then the  theorem of continuity won't work for all $\varepsilon $.

Precisely,

Let $a$ be any real number such that $a\neq 0$.

Suppose that $f(x)=0\; \forall x\in \mathbb{Q}$, and $f(x)=a\;  \forall x\notin \mathbb{Q}$.

Since $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, it is continuous at $x_{0}\in \mathbb{Q}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

Thus, $\forall\varepsilon> 0$, $\exists \delta > 0$ s.t

$x\in \mathbb{R},\left | x-x_{0} \right |< \delta$ implies $\left | f(x)-f(x_{0}) \right |<\varepsilon  $.

If $x\notin \mathbb{Q}$, then $\left | f(x)-f(x_{0}) \right |=\left | a \right |$.

This implies that for $x\notin \mathbb{Q}$, we can't pick any $\varepsilon$ s.t $0<\varepsilon\leq \left | a \right |$.

But, by the theorem, we must be able to pick any $\varepsilon>0$.

Therefore, this is a contradiction.

Thus, $f(x)\neq a\;  \forall x\notin \mathbb{Q}\Leftrightarrow f(x)=0 \; \forall x\notin \mathbb{Q}$

Hence, $f(x)=0 \; \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ $$\blacksquare $$

However, my proof seems wrong, but I can't tell why. "If there is something to fix," which part should I fix, and which way is better to prove this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the contrary, your approach is good. What I will say is that the presentation needs some tidying, which I suspect is the source of your doubt. Let's try putting it in a slightly different order:

Suppose $f(x_0) = a \neq 0$. Since $f$ is continuous, it is continuous at $x_0$. Considering $\varepsilon = |a| \neq 0$, there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that
$$|x - x_0| < \delta \implies |f(x) - a| < |a| \implies |a| - |f(x)| < |a| \implies |f(x)| > 0 \implies f(x) \neq 0.$$
Thus, every point $x \in (x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta)$ satisfies $f(x) \neq 0$. But, since $\Bbb{Q}$ is dense in $\Bbb{R}$, there must exist a rational point $q \in (x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta)$, which satisfies $f(q) = 0$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: Could you explain why we could use $|a|-|f(x)|$ instead of $||a|-|f(x)||$?

Comment: @john Well, $||a| - |f(x)||$ is always greater or equal to $|a| - |f(x)|$, so either way, we end up at the same point.

Comment: @john If you wish, we can just add another step in. We know that$$|f(x) - a| < |a| \implies ||a| - |f(x)|| \implies |a| - |f(x)| < |a|.$$

Comment: So, I tried to use the reverse triangle inequality "$||f(x)|-|a||\leq |f(x)-a|$". Then we get two cases such as "if $x\in \mathbb{Q}$, we get $|a|<|a|$ which is a contradiction, and "if $x\notin \mathbb{Q}$, then we get $0<|a|$. However, since we got the contradiction in case 1, we can conclude that $f(x)=a\neq 0$ is wrong. Is this right?

Comment: @john There's no need to break into cases at this stage. For any $x$, we have $x \le |x|$, and for any $x, y$, $||x| - |y|| \le |x - y|$. So, putting this together, we get$$|a| - |f(x)| \le ||a| - |f(x)|| \le |a - f(x)|.$$You can even show that $|a| = |a - f(x) + f(x)| \le |a - f(x)| + |f(x)|$, which implies $|a| - |f(x)| \le |a - f(x)|$ by regular triangle inequality. At this stage in the proof, the specific value of $a$ and $f(x)$ are immaterial.

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to know this well fact . If $f,g\colon \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ continuous functions and $$f(x)=g(x)$$ for all $x\in D$ where $D$ is dense subset of $\Bbb R$ then $f(x)=g(x)$ for every $x\in \Bbb R$ chekc?

Now, $f(x)=O(x)$ for every $x\in \Bbb Q$ where $O$ is a zero function. By using the fact above $f(x)=0$ for every $x\in\Bbb Q$

Answer (score 1):

Just to prove that for any $\epsilon > 0 $ have the following,
$$
|f(x)|<\epsilon
$$
this implies that $f(x) \equiv 0$

what we know is $f(x) = 0$ for $x\in\mathbb{Q}$,
for $x \not\in \mathbb{Q}$ , we can find a sequence $x_n \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x_n \to x $ as $ n \to \infty $, because $f$ is continuous , that means for any $\epsilon > 0$ ,we can find the $\delta > 0$ such that only $|x_n-x| < \delta $ for some $n>N$ , there have the following
$$
|f(x_n)-f(x)| < \epsilon 
$$
note that $f(x_n) = 0$ , then we get what we want to prove.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a neater proof:

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}$. It suffices to show that $|f(x)|=0$. Let $\epsilon>0$. As $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, there exists some $\delta>0$ such that whenever $y\in (x-\delta,x+\delta)$ then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. So in particular choosing a rational $q$ in $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$, we have $|f(x)-f(q)|=|f(x)|<\epsilon$.  $\square$

Additionally, let us adapt the technique in the proof above to the following result:

**Proposition:**

Let $D\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a dense subset. Suppose $f,g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are continuous and they agree on $D$. Then $f=g$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Proof:

It suffices to show that if $h: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function such that $h=0$ on $D$ then $h=0$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon>0$. By continuity of $h$ on $\mathbb{R}$, there exists some $\delta>0$ such that whenever $y\in (x-\delta,x+\delta)$ we have $|h(x)-h(y)|<\epsilon$.
As $D$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, $D\cap (x-\delta,x+\delta) \neq \varnothing$. Thus picking one element, $d$, from the intersection we obtain $|h(x)-h(d)|=|h(x)|<\epsilon$. $\square$